# DaVinci Resolve won't start Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

So finally free version of Resolve has arrived, but after I installed it on my notebook it doesn't start. Can someone help me out?

Comment: What happens when you try to start it? If the answer is "nothing", then try running it from a terminal and see if it outputs anything.

Comment: also waiting for an answer.. in the meantime i will start combing through the Blackmagic Forums
https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=56878

Comment: To debug the problem run `ldd /opt/resolve/bin/resolve` to test for dependencies and check `/opt/resolve/logs/` or `~/.local/share/DaVinciResolve/logs/` for error logs.

Answer (score 2):

Installing `libssl-dev` and a few symbolic link solves the problem. Please enter the commands below:

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0 /usr/lib/libgstbase-0.10.so.0
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libssl.so.10
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10
```

---

([Source](https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=58668))

Comment: After overcoming this installation problem (missing requirement/dependency), the next challenge is this error message at the start of the installed app: "Please initialize the log4cxx system properly." And to overcome this, you should go to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/978660/how-to-fix-log4cxx-please-initialize-the-log4cxx-system-properly