# how to fix "log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly."

Tags: lubuntu

I've been having issues with DaVinci Resolve.

When starting I get the following error:

```
log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (UI).
log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properlyhe log4cxx system properly.
14.1 (#018)<br>
Main thread starts: 51F05600<br>
[0x7f0f51f05600] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2017-11-21 17:34:40,626 | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[0x7f0f51f05600] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2017-11-21 17:34:40,626 | Loaded log config from /opt/resolve/configs/log-conf.xml
[0x7f0f51f05600] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2017-11-21 17:34:40,626 | --------------------------------------------------------
```

Could this be a problem with how I set up resolve, how do I "initialize the log4cxx system properly"?

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks,
Braedon.

Comment: https://github.com/smartdevicelink/sdl_core/issues/809#issuecomment-246478996

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that but I don't really understand what they're talking about (i'm a newbie to linux)

Comment: Please follow user `BTPankow` from that link to see if it resolves it!

Comment: try stating the program as root?